# Waffle chart with 2 categories and raw counts fills out final column with a mysterious 3rd category of made up data

Tags: r, graph, waffle-chart

I'm trying to make a waffle chart of raw counts and only two categories. For some reason it makes up enough counts of a mysterious 3rd category to fill out the final column. With three or more categories the final column is partially filled as I intend. How do I make this work with just two categories?

My code:

```
library(waffle)

test2 <- c(`Group A`= 40, `Group B`= 33)
test3 <- c(`Group A`= 40, `Group B`= 33, `Group c` =10)

#test2 fails, test3 works as intended
waffle(test2)  
waffle(test3)
```

images below

Comment: By default the `rows = 10`.  i.e. if you change it to multiple of 10s, then it gives two categories instead of filling with an empty one `test2 <- c(`Group A`= 40, `Group B`= 20)`

Comment: @akrun  it fills out the rectangle with the mystery third category regardless. waffle(test2, rows=20) also fills the rectangle. Perhaps I don't understand your answer

Comment: If you use the example I showed, it is giving only 2 categories (for me)

Comment: When I run your code I get 2 categories and full columns. That would be great if that was my data. Did you cut n' paste my code as is? I can't use your code as I need my data to be my actual data and not to be a multiple of 10 (or any other row number)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a bug in the source code

Comment: Issue submitted in github  https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle/issues/77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I get it the issue is related to the fact that the default color brewer palette returns three colors, i.e `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(2, "Set2")` will return a vector of three colors. To solve this issue you have to explicitly specify that you want to have only two colors in your waffle chart. Try this:

```r
library(waffle)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

test2 <- c(`Group A`= 40, `Group B`= 33)

waffle(test2, colors = c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set2")[1:2]))
```

[image]